# Test react onClick event with tape

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, babeljs

I want to test onClick event on React with Tape. The documentation says that all you have to do is to just call directly the onClick event callback before comparison. But when I call handleSubmit event before the comparison I get an error- handleSubmit is not defined.

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
    import {createRenderer} from 'react-addons-test-utils';
    import tape from 'tape';
    import addAssertions from 'extend-tape';
    import jsxEquals from 'tape-jsx-equals';

    const test = addAssertions(tape, {jsxEquals});

    class MyComponent extends Component{
      constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {text: 'here is text'}
      }
      handleSubmit(e){
            this.setState({text: 'new text'})
      }
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
              {this.state.text}
              <button onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Update</button>
            </div>
        );
      }
    };

    test('MyComponent is properly rendered', (t) => {
        t.plan(1);
        const text = 'here is text'
        const renderer = createRenderer();
        renderer.render(<MyComponent />);
        const result = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        handleSubmit();
        t.jsxEquals(result, <div>{text}<button onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Update</button></div>);
        t.end();
    });
```